# sql-server change login password

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 and when I create a new login and enter the password for the first time, this window appears and asks to change the password. How can I do what this window does using SQL code, for example, in a query?. I tried to use SQL Server Profiler selecting security changes to be traced, but I could not find any entry in the record that corresponds to the window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `commands` means and also what version of MSSQL you target, but I think your best chance is to use `Microsoft Sql Server Management Objects`(Smo). This library has a function called `ChangePassword` inside `Login` class. 
Reference on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.login.changepassword.aspx)